# Translate "Good for you"

Tags: traducción

Is there a way to translate "Good for you" into Spanish? The literal translation would be "Buen para ti" but it does not sound correct.

Comment: Welcome to our community! "Tú" is the subjective form, so you must use "ti" in this case, as it's the object. Otherwise your literal translation is pretty close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say:

> Bien por ti.

"Bien por ti" is almost always used sarcastically. How sarcastic it sounds depends mostly on your tone. For example, I would use "Bien por ti" to congratulate someone if I'm talking to them but I would never write it because it would most likely be misunderstood. If you don't want to sound sarcastic, a safer option would be:

> Me alegro por ti.

You can substitute that "ti" with "ustedes/vosotros" to make it plural. As pointed out by Marco in the comments, you may also encounter the less common version "Bien por vos" in dialects with [*voseo*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo), such as Rioplatense Spanish (Argentina and Uruguay), Eastern Bolivia, and Paraguayan Spanish, according to the Wikipedia.

Comment: Even though, *me alegro por ti* is still sarcastic, it all depends how it's taken.

Comment: @yay me gustaría agregar: "Bien por vos" (en Argentina lo decimos así)

Comment: @Marco Ah, I forgot about that! Thanks, I've already added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see you are trying to translate "Good for you" from a non sarcastic perspective.

Literal translation will be: "Bien por ti" but you will hardly hear someone say something like that. Even "Me alegro por ti" does not apply to the common language.

You will probably hear something like: "¡Qué bueno!" or "¡Qué bien!"

In both cases "you" is implied in the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

"Good for you" can also be said in the sense that something is good for your(self):

**Comer fruta es bueno para ti**

This is very usually said in Spain omitting **para ti** itself and leaving it to the context:

> Comer fruta es bueno (para ti / para mí / para vosotros / para todos ... )
>
> Tomar drogas es malo (para ti / ...)

Answer (score -1):

You should try:

- *Bien por usted* (*ustedes* for plural), if its formal
- *Bien por ti* informally